# aws s3 image downloads instead of view on browser using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying something like

```
response = s3_client.generate_presigned_post(bucket_name,
                                                     object_name,
                                                     Fields=fields,
                                                     Conditions=conditions,
                                                     ExpiresIn=expiration)
```

when I upload and preview the image.. It downloads the image instead of previewing

I added `[["startswith", "$Content-Type", ""]` in `Conditions` variable but then it gives me error saying policy didnt match

Does anyone has faced this issue. I do not want to match with `image/jpeg` or something I want it to accept any file.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to match with image/jpeg or something I want it to accept any file.

You **have to match it**. Content-Type is part of the signature which is illustrated in the [AWS example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html) for making `Signature Version 4` signatures.